# Different answer when deriving Euler-Cauchy equation (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This is the standard proof of euler's formula:

https://www.utdallas.edu/studentsuccess/mathlab/PatricksPDFs/euler.pdf

However, I tried it a different way and I seem to get a different answer.

They find that

$(\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}= x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac {dy}{dx} )$

However isn't this true as well? :

$x=e^t$

$\frac {dt}{dx} = e^{-t}$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dt}{dx} \frac {dy}{dt}  = e^{-t}\frac {dy}{dt}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac {dt}{dx} \frac {d^2y}{dt^2} + \frac {d^2t}{dx^2} \frac {dy}{dt}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = e^{-t}\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} - e^t\frac {dy}{dt}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = e^{-t}(\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac {dy}{dt})$

$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} = e^t\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} +  \frac {dy}{dt}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}=x\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac {dy}{dx}$

I really don't see where my mistake is, so if someone could help me out I'd very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is your fourth step:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt})=\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{d\mathbf{x}dt}+\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dt}=\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dt}=\\=e^{-2t}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-e^{-2t}\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-2t}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$
Notice the boldfaced $x$ in the second expression.
From This we have
$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-x\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Analogously, it is $x\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}$ as $x\frac{dt}{dx}=1$

Therefore, Cauchy-Euler eq. $ax^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+bx\frac{dy}{dx}+cy=0$ can be rewritten as
$$a\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+(b-a)\frac{dy}{dt}+cy=0$$
q.e.d.

Comment: Nevermind my old comment, realized my mistake the way I did it, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome.